# Mixed Content: HTTP issue

Tags: javascript

I don't make any insecure requests, I call an API over https but somehow an Http request appears in the network tab in chrome dev tool which i didn't make but from the same API

I searched my whole project, all the protocols are Https.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQkmB.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Nsh.png

The actual request

```
export const getPGCR = instanceId => {
  return axios.get(
    `https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny2/Stats/PostGameCarnageReport/${instanceId}/`,
    {
      headers: {
        "X-API-KEY": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
      }
    }
  );
};
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getPGCR } from "../utility/endpoints";
import Loading from "../components/Loading";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class PGCR extends Component {
  state = {
    pgcr: "",
    loading: true,
    activityNotFound: false
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const instanceId = parseInt(this.props.match.params.instanceId);
      const pgcrResult = await getPGCR(instanceId);

      this.setState({ pgcr: pgcrResult.data.Response }, () => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response.data.ErrorCode === 1653) {
        this.setState({ loading: false, activityNotFound: true });
      } else if (err.response.data.ErrorCode === 5) {
        this.props.failGetData();
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    if (!this.state.loading) {
      if (!this.state.activityNotFound) {
        return (
          <div className="infamy-container">
            <div className="track-wrapper">
              {this.state.pgcr.entries.map((entry, index) => {
                const player = {
                  name: entry.player.destinyUserInfo.displayName,
                  icon: `https://www.bungie.net${
                    entry.player.destinyUserInfo.iconPath
                  }`,
                  completed: entry.values.completed.basic.displayValue,
                  kills: entry.values.kills.basic.displayValue,
                  deaths: entry.values.deaths.basic.displayValue
                };
                return (
                  <div key={index} className="track-container">
                    <div
                      className="track-container--effect track-container--effect_pgcr"
                      style={{
                        backgroundImage: `url(${player.icon})`
                      }}
                    />
                    <div className="track-container--content">
                      <div>
                        <h4>{player.name}</h4>
                      </div>
                      <ul className="center-ul">
                        <li>Kills: {player.kills}</li>
                        <li>Deaths: {player.deaths}</li>
                        <li>Completed: {player.completed}</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <div className="infamy-container">
            <div className="error_activity">Activity Not Found</div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="infamy-container">
          <Loading />;
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

const mapStoreToProps = store => {
  return {
    player: store.player
  };
};

export const failGetData = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "FAIL_SET_DATA",
        payload: "Bungie API is down at this moment, please try again later"
      });
      resolve();
    });
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStoreToProps,
  { failGetData }
)(PGCR);
```

Comment: Hey there. Can you try to provide a minimal as possible, self containing, example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I already provided everything, what's more should i provide? why people downvoting, it's not same as other questions

Comment: I would say if your code is making a `http://` call, then your search was not comprehensive enough.  We can't tell you anything beyond "its there, you just didn't find it."

Comment: I searched the whole project there is no Http requests, the only request i make in this page is the above url

Comment: I put the whole code of the page

Comment: So you are searching for "http://"?  Again, if the request is being made, but you can't find it, then all we can tell you is your search wasn't able to turn it up.  I don't know what you expect us to tell you.

Comment: All the endpoints are in one file and i have 9 endpoints, all of them have https

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the request is being made from one of the libraries you're using?  Because `stats.bungie.net` is nowhere in the code you have provided.

Comment: There is no library from this website and i searched the whole project but a friend told me the request is 301, the API makes this redirect. in the response headers there is the same url with http in property of `location`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the API has a 301 redirect which wrongly redirect to a http protocol and caused the app to break.
They confirmed it is a bug on github